# Calling external contract leads to infinite gas need

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, out-of-gas

I'm trying to implement this pattern:

```
contract Producer {
  uint8 public SOME_VALUE=12;
}
contract Consumer {
  Producter currentProducer;
  function setProducer(address addr) { currentProducer = Producer(addr); }
  function getSome() returns (uint8) { return currentProducer.SOME_VALUE(); }
}
```

It compiles, I can deploy my Consumer, and I can it bind a producer.

But I want to ensure addr is really a Producer when I bind it to my Consumer:

```
function setProducer(address addr) { 
    Producer newProducer = Producer(addr);
    require(newProducer.SOME_VALUE() > 0);
    currentProducer =newProducer; 
}
```

This way, I'm sure I'm linking a Producer and not anything else (I don't like the way I do this, but that's the best solution I found yet)

But by just adding this require, I'm no more able to deploy. The gas needed is sky rocketing... may be infinite as, no matter how high I put it, the transaction fails after reaching the limit (Same behavior on Remix or on a local testnet). Please note that, a the time of deployment, the setProducer() function is not called.

Is this a bug? Or most probable: am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented your code adding a few details and it works. The only odd thing is that you define the type `Producter` and is `Producer`. So the problems is basically a typo. (it happens)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Producer {
  uint8 public SOME_VALUE=12;
}

contract Consumer {
    Producer currentProducer;

    function setProducer(address addr) public { 
        Producer newProducer = Producer(addr);
        require(newProducer.SOME_VALUE() > 0);
        currentProducer =newProducer; 
    }

    function getSome() public view returns (uint8) {
        return currentProducer.SOME_VALUE(); 

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaime. My bad: there was a mistake in the sample code I provided. In the original one, the state variable was set in its declaration (I edited my post to correct). Furthermore, I found out that the issue was not in the particular "require()" I pointed out. If I comment out any random line calling the Producer, I can deploy... it fails only when all calls to Producer functions are left uncommented. #headhache

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer, you have a typo in the code. I implemented and test it using remix. See the detail in the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same using solidity version 0.7.0 but I am getting error